# c++ : How can I read lines in form "zab 1 2 3 4 5 S" without being allowed to use string?

Tags: c++, input, char, integer

So I have this really annoying homework - it's about self implemented lists.
But horror starts much sooner - at the level of feeding the program with data.

I need to be able to read input in format:

- three small letters without space (this would be unique identifier of list)
- unlimited number of integers ( from -2^31 to 2^31 ) (this would be the content of list)
- letter R or S (this would mean if numbers are to be stored in the same order that they were entered or in the reverse order) - those letters mean end of input for a given list

So input should look like this:

- zab 1 2 3 4 5 S
- cvr 9 8 7 R
- xxx S

The trick is that I'm not allowed to use ANYTHING BESIDES iostream.
In particular, this mean that:

- sstream, fstream, istream, ostream, cstdio etc.
- array, list, vector, queue etc.
- symbols [ , ] , <: and :>
- words string and class

ARE FORBIDDEN.

My problems are:

- I have no idea how to read three letters ( like zab, gad, pkf ) with restrictions as above? I guess I would store them as three chars, but first i must get them.
- I have no idea how to read any number of integers and stop when there is S or R as an input, but still be able to read and store S or R.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

EDIT:
The solution to read three letters provided by Joachim Pileborg:

## include

using namespace std;

int main () {

```
char x1;
char x2;
char x3;

cin.get(x1);
cin.get(x2);
cin.get(x3);

cout << x1 <<  x2 <<  x3 << endl;

return 0;
```

}

The rest I will try to do in similar way, with integers produced via multiplication of chars that have been read.

Comment: Read about [`std::istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). Reading the numbers might prove harder though, especially if the limit on using `>` also prevents `>>`.

Comment: Can't use ostream or istream?  Which pretty much puts the kibosh on doing anything with iostream.

Comment: Also, you can't use `class`, but what about `struct`?

Comment: struct is allowed - without it the task would be rather impossible

Comment: If this is indeed the list of your restrictions verbatim, your instructor has no idea what he's doing. Just have to inform you.

Comment: Then how about creating a double-linked list (once you know how to get the numbers that is)?

Comment: Also, you *can* get the numbers digit by digit (i.e. character by character) and use multiplication to create the final number. So *if* you can call `std::cin.get` then it can be solved.

Comment: So far, 41 out of ~ 120 students succeed. This is introductory course in Programming. Unfortunately I have very little contact with other students, as this is my additional course I took after I graduated, so I don't know how they did it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I like this idea. I would try to get it work.

Comment: so basically this is a c program not a c++ program. use scanf etc.

Comment: scanf is in cstdio, which is forbidden :(

Comment: "how to read three letters". Can you read one letter? can you count to three?

Comment: those letters are to be typed without spaces between them

Comment: The idea of forbid `class` but allow `struct` is... funny. I'm wondering what does your teacher think the differences between the two are.

Comment: class is forbidden because it was not in the lecture yet. this is introductory course. I guess it is to prevent students from copying solutions (the list implementation part) from the internet and to make them think.

Comment: std::cin is of type std::istream btw, maybe your teacher want you to feed the program using main arguments. This restriction " Cant use symbols [ , ] , <: and :>" is nonsensical.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest nonsense like building the word `string` from preprocessor instead of writing it in readable code but I guess that would be unfair to the question. I think you have to be a bit more specific about your problems... Do you know, how to read in a single number character by character? Do you know, how to read in a sequence of numbers? Do you know how to store the read-in numbers? What are the output requirements of the program (storing is no use in itself)?

Comment: How do you input characters or numbers if you can't use `iostream` or `stdio`?  The `cstdio` contains information for `stdin`, `stdout`, `getchar`, etc.  Are you allowed to use OS API to fetch characters?  Or do you have to use hard-coded input?

Comment: Regarding that edit, you tell `get` that it can read *two* characters, and put into a *single* character. That will lead to problems (and something called *undefined behavior*). Instead just do e.g. `std::cin.get(x1)` to read a single character.

Comment: As for the number, lets say the input is `123`, then you read the `1` and add to a (zero initialized) variable. Read another *character* and if it's a digit then multiply the variable with `10` and add the second digit (which leads to the variables value being `12`), the do the same for the next character (the variable is now `123`). When you read the next character it will no longer be a digit and you stop reading the number.

Comment: Also note that [the `get` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) *returns* the stream, and that a stream [can be used as a boolean](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), so if there's no more input you can check e.g. `if (!std::cin) { /* nothing more to read */ }`.